# Reactjs-Adding chat bubbles from bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a chat screen wanted to append chat bubble from bottom of the div as we have seen in our applications like WhatsApp or FBMessenger.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a component (the tab and chat window) and position it static on the bottom (similar to a hamburger menu but the opposite way around).

The actual presentation aspect of the component is almost identical to the hamburger menu.

The functional component would be different as it needs to be responsive. (hint: it will involve a service that communicates information from the server to the client).